# Explanation of Intellij undo.documentUndoLimit and undo.globalUndoLimit

Tags: intellij-idea

What do these settings actually do?

What values should a pro have on these and what impact do they have? Refactoring undo for instance, "X file has already changed so you can not undo" would be **GREAT** if we could throw in the garbage using any setting combination.

[image]

Comment: `documentUndoLimit` the undo limit for current Document. `globalUndoLimit` - the undo limit for global IDE undo stack. Note that these options are already set to their  most suitable defaults and should not be edited in normal situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25014049/6877799) the `documentUndoLimit` is the max level of **undo** for each document (actually current document) and the `globalUndoLimit` is the undo max level of **undo** for the IDE on the current project.

For example, when you change codes of a file and then decide to undo the `documentUndoLimit` value is the number of levels that you can go back. but when you add some files or delete some other files, rename them and etc, the `globalUndoLimit` value is the number of levels that you can go back.

Comment: This is kind of broken nowadays in Intellij I feel. Is there a way to avoid having Intellij complain about not possible to undo due to changes in other files? It did not used to be like this back in the days. Annoying as fcuk. Might have to do with my settings of these. 1000 and 100. I will post a new question about that.. It is time to stop that annoyance.

Comment: @mmm, I'm eager to see your new post about this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919266/stop-intellij-from-preventing-from-undo-changes-in-a-file-due-to-changes-globall?noredirect=1#comment107784477_60919266