# Stop Intellij from preventing from undo changes in a file due to changes globally in the project

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes, when you **undo**, maybe not in serial, Intellij will complain that it is **unable** to undo due to some **global changes** which can be very **annoying** to get around forcing you to use **local** **history** even though all you want is undo.

I understand that if you refactored then changed in those files, and then you undo in a file that would require a rewind of those others which might have changed since, makes the undo  difficult to perform.

At **least** then you should be able to continue to **undo** **locally** only, **regardless** if that change affected other files.

Meaning the undo will only affect this file and leave all others intact. That is the behavior you would get when **resetting** that file **from** **local** **history** which is time consuming and often annoying to parse through.

Sometimes when refactoring you might need to go back locally to copy some piece of code, and undo is sometimes pretty useful way of getting there and back.

It could also be for reasons such manually manipulating the refactoring environment, using tricks the IDEA can not.

Local history is just obtrusive to use. The undo did not use to work like this 5 years ago for sure.

**Can we enable something?**

Maybe related: 
[Explanation of Intellij undo.documentUndoLimit and undo.globalUndoLimit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59423614/explanation-of-intellij-undo-documentundolimit-and-undo-globalundolimit/60917199#60917199)

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one that's annoyed by this. Why isn't there a better per document Undo? I don't care what I did in other files, I want *this* file to go back to what it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have such an option/feature.

Comment: can you confirm wether back in the days this wasn't a restriction? It's annoying that your undo simply and constantly breaks. I mean sometimes it can complain upon 10 other files have changed since. I mean worst case it could in principle offer to undo those things there as well, alternatively allow the local undo to progress. Like a command shift z/y to force locally. and shift option to force global changes to undo as well.

Comment: Many people will also use it to jump locally to peek as well by undoing and redoing because bookmarks are not that reliable. Also last edit location is a global thing.

Comment: As far as I remember it was always a restriction.

Comment: I can't ever remember this occuring between 2008 - 2012